# Filtering a Rethinkdb table on some element of a nested object

Tags: python, json, nested, rethinkdb

I am having hard times with understanding how to filter my rethinkdb table with Python based on substring match on a nested element of the following data:

```
{
// HERE WE HAVE MANY RECORDS
    "record":  "0a76d012-f83d-4bd3-95b7-2ba973750bde" ,
    "steps": 
    [ 
// HERE WE HAVE MANY STEPS
        {
            "step": 1,
            "latest_db_info": { ... } ,
            "data": 
            [
               {
                    "hash":  "2ba7e669" ,
                    "name":  "Numero de l'extrait" ,
                    "position": 1 ,
                    "value":  "Limoges_34"
                } ,
                {
                    "hash":  "d094874e" ,
                    "name":  "Numero de page de l'extrait" ,
                    "position": 2 ,
                    "value":  "Limoges_p. 34"
                } ,
                {
                    "hash":  "598653a6" ,
                    "name":  "Type de l'extrait" ,
                    "position": 3 ,
                    "value":  "texte"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What i want, for example, is to get is all the records that have:

- a substring matching 'mog' for the field 'value'
- and at the same time matching 'Numero de page' for the field 'name'

For example the path to the field 'value' is something like:

```
{'steps': [{'data': [['value' ...
```

I tried with direct filtering, on a `lambda function` and does not give any results.
I reached some results with `concat_map`:

```
r.table('mytable') \
    .concat_map(r.row['steps']) \
    .concat_map(r.row['data']) \
    .filter(
        lambda row: row['value'].match('mog')
    ).run()
```

But the results loose the original `record` field...

```
[{'position': 1, 'hash': '2ba7e669', 'value': 'Limoges_34', 'name': "Numero de l'extrait"}, 
[...]
```

Could someone please lead me in the right direction?
Also a javascript example would help.

**EDIT**: accepted answer worked, thanks to @kureikain. This is the python version for future references:

```
r.table('mytable') \
    .concat_map(
        lambda doc: doc['steps'] \
            .concat_map(lambda step: step['data'] \
                .concat_map(lambda data: [{'record': doc['record'], 'step': data}]
    ))) \
  .filter(
    lambda doc: 
        doc['step']['value'].match('mog').and_(doc['step']['name'].match('Numero de page'))
  ).run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with nested syntax only works with nested object, we don't have a way to select/query an array with nested syntax.

If you want to include `record` field and `step/data` records that match your value, you can use sth like this:

```
r.table('mytable')
  .concatMap(function(doc) {
    return doc('steps')
      .concatMap(function(step) {
        return step('data').concatMap(function(data) {
          return [{record: doc('record'), step: data}]
        })
      })
  })

  .filter(function(doc) {
    return doc('step')('value').eq('mog').and(doc('step')('name').eq('Numero de page'))
  })
```

Or another way, without using `filter`

```
r.table('mytable')
  .concatMap(function(doc) {
    return doc('steps')
      .concatMap(function(step) {
        return step('data').concatMap(function(data) {
          return
            r.branch(data('value').eq('Limoges_34').and(data('name').eq('Numero de l\'extrait')),
              [{record: doc('record'), step: data}],
              [])
        })
      })
  })
```

Comment: It works! Thanks, didn't know concatmap was so powerful combined with lambda. I really like the first solution, it divides in two the query: 1) preparing the result set, 2) making the filter. I will edit my answer to write the Python equivalent. Can i also ask you if the data structure does not fit well Rethinkdb? Maybe i should find a way to write also arrays as dictionaries?